# Does Nuget package KnockoutMvc support WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, knockout-mvc

I'm developing a MVC website, just trying out this Nuget package, KnockoutMvc. And it seems all controllers have to inherit from KnockoutController, KnockoutController is inherit from Controller. I can't find anything which is linking for ApiController.

So the question will be does this package support WebApi? If it does, how can it be done?

If it's possible, guidelines and sample code will be great.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: KnockoutController subclasses Controller, which is being used by the MVC (4) framework. ApiController is an entire new set of controllers used by the Web Api framework.

Comment: @drch sorry man, I couldn't understand what u mean, which bit doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Jordy Yes, I know that part. KnockoutMvc seems convert Json string to the Context KnockoutMvc is using, I'm just wondering if there are any way we could directly pass json string to KnockoutMvc, and create the Context it's using.